# How to reload tableview after didendeditmethod (entering text )of textfield

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield, reload

I am having a tableview and each row of it  having textfield.

Now after textFieldDidEndEditing: (after entering some text) i am performing some database operation.

So again i want to reload the table.

how i can i do that .

thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call this method where ever you want to reload the tableview

```
[tableview reloadData];
```